# how to stop receiveing wait for debugger to attach"

Tags: android

I am using a real device to test my App, and when I click on te icon of the App, I receive `Waiting For Debugger To Attach`

how to stop receiving this message.?

Answer (score 0):

Hey it seems that you are running your application in debug mode. You can resolve this issue by removing android:debuggable="true" from your AndroidManifest.xml file when you want to test the application by itself. Turning off development options in the preferences menu will help also.

Comment: but when i run the App now, at certain point, the debugger perspective automatically appears an active? how to stop that?

Comment: it should go on recompiling your application.

Comment: ok but how to stop the debugger perspective to appear automatically?

Comment: It will not come when you will finally export your apk for going live

Comment: click on debug, it will show option to set it to default. I think after that it willl not come